# Android Studio - Not able to push my code into GitHub Enterprise with new system and older backed-up files...what to do

Tags: git, android-studio, github, gitlab

SSH error: Permission denied, please try again

I have worked on some project in my System and because of certain Reason i had to replace my System and I have taken backup for all my android project files.

When i tried to Build same project in new System i am not able to push my code to the GitHub

Comment: Try to delete project from device and re-import from git through SSH or HTTP url. Maybe your project not connected with your git project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have taken backup for all my android project files.

That might not be enough: SSH would use key files in `~/.ssh` (your `$HOME/.ssh` on Linux/Mac, or `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`).

If you have not transferred those, you would need to regenerate a new key pair, and [register the public key to GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), in order to restore authentication.